# flex item with image child doesn't adjust its size properly

Tags: css, flexbox

I found this post, [Flex item with image child doesn't adjust from its original width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417182/flex-item-with-image-child-doesnt-adjust-from-its-original-width), which I initial thought had the answer, but it didn't, ... well partially it did, when a set height is used.

What I want and expect to happen here, is that the image matches the text element's height and then adjust its width while keeping its ratio.

This appears to work in Chrome, but not in Edge/IE/Firefox. Haven't been able to test Safari as I don't have an iOS device, so I would appreciate if someone can share how/if it work there.

This doesn't need to be a `flexbox` solution, though I expect a CSS one, meaning ***no script***.

---

**Edit**

The given text's height could be dynamic, and based on its content, so the predefined `200px` was simply to give it a height, [JSFiddle demo, set height](https://jsfiddle.net/7zgh88ew/9/)  .

---

[JSFiddle demo, content based height](https://jsfiddle.net/7zgh88ew/10/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.img img {
  height:100%;
}

.text {
  background: lightblue;
}

.text-content {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x90">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="text-content">
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Expected result (hard coded)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.img img {
  height:100%;
  width: 355px;            /*  force correct width  */
}

.text {
  background: lightblue;
}

.text-content {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x90">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="text-content">
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
      Some text content<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To make things worse, a local copy  (that I believe reproduces **exactly** your snippet) is failing in Chrome   ...

Comment: @vals Interesting ... made one local version myself and it worked in my Chrome (ver. 57, 64-bit, on Windows 10 Pro)

Comment: @vals Does this version work for you, locally? ... https://jsfiddle.net/f8hgnr77/

Comment: Yes, your new fiddle works locally   I just can't understand what is going on. I have posted a not-an-aswer to see if someone can spot the reason of this behaviour

Comment: @Michael_B Do you have any idea about these issues, both mine and what _vals_ posted?

Comment: @Oriol What is your take on these issues?

Comment: Unluckily Oriol is no longer visiting S.O.  (And It's a pity)

Comment: @vals Didn't know (and agree)

Comment: @LGSon, currently I have nothing more to add to the answers and comments already posted. Well, maybe one thing: The seemingly random behavior of images in flex items and flex containers is pretty annoying.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for taking the time

Comment: @vals FYI...got a comment from Michael

Comment: Thanks for telling me. The sad part is that we still don't have a solution ...

Comment: @vals, re: Oriol FYI... https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for the note

Comment: @Michael_B Is this solvable using CSS Grid?

Comment: @LGSon, in looking at your code sample and fiddle demos, and before I delve into this for you, please note that `height: 100%` on the `img` elements have no parent heights defined. See here for guidance (although I think you already know this): [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: Try a nested flex container to give the image full height.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks, and yes, I know that :) ...will have a look later and let you know

Answer (score 4):

You should define the height at the `.container` level. Following CSS will work for all the browsers you mentioned above:

```
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 200px;
}

.img {
    height: 100%;
}
.img img {
    height:100%;
}

.text {
    background: lightblue;
}

.text-content {
    width: 200px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'll leave the old answer just in case but this seems to work [codepen](https://codepen.io/tuncelmert/pen/JNyQoy).
I've tried with varying number of lines and text sizes.

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.img img {
  height:100%;
}

.text {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. Made a minor edit of the question, where the height could be dynamic and based on the content of the text element

Comment: @LGSon I've updated the answer, can you please check the codepen?

Comment: Just did, if you check in Firefox and Edge, you see it still does not work