# How can I grow/shrink an image to the same height as its flex item sibling?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49065029/11942268), I try to shrink/grow a flex-item `img` element to the height of its sibling. The height gets adjusted correctly, and the image is shrunk correctly - respecting the aspect ratio - but the `img` element still consumes as much width as it would without shrinking it (look at the whitespace):

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid black;
}

img {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  object-fit: contain;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>Match my height.</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Actual output, in case browsers (will) render the above snippet differently (in the future):

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

I also tried to set `overflow-x: auto;` or `width: 100%` (on `img`), but it did not make any difference. Is there a way to get the *expected* shrunk image dimensions in this flexbox layout?

There are many similar questions, but they don't offer the above flexbox solution. Just to name some:

- [Grow/Shrink flex item to fit image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44421262/11942268)
- [How do I set a flex-item's height to the same height as it's sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58894818/11942268)
- [Make flex item siblings the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52615329/11942268)
- [How to set flex item height equally [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46127923/11942268)

So, there are alternatives if there is no flexbox solution...

Comment: The img does not have a sibling.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-grid-item-sets-the-size-limit-for-siblings?r=SearchResults&s=13%7C24.2725

Comment: @Paulie_D it's about the width of the image that need to shrink

Comment: @AHaworth Technically, yes ;-) The _flexbox workaround_ requires a wrapper around the items. So the `section` elements only exist because of that.

Comment: Do yu have to stick with flex?

Comment: @AHaworth Actually, I think my design might be wrong. If I want that image to have the height of another element, then it is not flexible at all. And therefore, it should not be a flex item. But I am currently doing more research on this...

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have better luck with CSS grid but I think this won't work in all the browsers.

Chrome will give a good result but Firefox will fail

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  place-content: start;
}

section {
  border: thin solid black;
}

img {
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  </section>

  <section>
    <div>Match my height.</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: It does indeed not work in Firefox. As you own the CSS and flexbox gold badges... Can you say, that it is not possible to solve my problem with flexible boxes? I mean... "It's impossible." could be a valid answer to my problem, until someone else proves it wrong (in the future).

Comment: @stackprotector I am not sure at 100% that's it's impossible but I know the "complex" reasons that make such layout not easy to achieve. You question can remain open and a new answer can be added at any time (either to confirm it's impossible or to give a solution)